# generate different columns by keeping different duplicate indexes in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Lets say I have a DataFrame which looks like this:

```
      D1    
0   2827  
1   2861 
2   2861  
3   2861  
4   2861  
5   2177  
6   2113  
7   2113  
8   2711  
9   2067  
10  2067  
11  2067 
12  2957 
13  2407  
14  2893
```

Then I would like to have all different combinations of dataframe columns which replace the duplicates with a string "blank" and keep the uniques.

In the dataframe there are only 9 unique values, thus 6 duplicates should be blanked.

As output i would expect a combination:

```
      D1    
0   2827  
1   2861 
2   "blank"  
3   "blank"  
4   "blank"  
5   2177  
6   2113  
7   "blank"  
8   2711  
9   2067  
10  "blank"  
11  "blank" 
12  2957 
13  2407  
14  2893
```

and another combination...

```
  D1    
0   2827  
1   "blank" 
2   2861  
3   "blank"  
4   "blank"  
5   2177  
6   "blank 
7   2113  
8   2711  
9   "blank"  
10  2067  
11  "blank" 
12  2957 
13  2407  
14  2893
```

Until all combinations of blanking are made, while preserving their index.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should include your attempts (code) to solve your issue. What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider groupby's `cumcount` and conditionally (using numpy's `where`) update any value higher than zero. Do note: since you require a string *"blank"* replacement, the entire column must be converted to string (i.e., object):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    
from itertools import permutations
from functools import reduce
from io import StringIO

text="""
    D1   
0   2827  
1   2861  
2   2861
3   2861
4   2861
5   2177
6   2113
7   2113
8   2711
9   2067
10  2067
11  2067
12  2957
13  2407
14  2893"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep="\s+")

# BUILDS LIST OF SERIES FROM EACH COLUMN OF DATAFRAME
df['Cnt'] = df.groupby(['D1']).cumcount()
df['MaxCnt'] = df.groupby(['D1'])['Cnt'].transform(max)

combfactor = reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, df.groupby(['D1'])['Cnt'].transform('count').unique())

# RETRIEVE COMBINATIONS FOR EACH GROUP
def createcombs(grp):    
    perms = list(permutations(df[df['D1']==grp]['Cnt'].tolist(), 
                              len(df[df['D1']==grp]['Cnt'].tolist())))        
    perms = int(round(combfactor/len(perms),0)) * perms   

    return pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*perms)))

df = df.join(pd.concat([createcombs(g) for g in df['D1'].unique()], ignore_index=True))    

# COLUMN BINDS INTO NEW DATAFRAME
serlist = [pd.Series(np.where((df[i] != j) & (df['MaxCnt']!=0), '"blank"', df['D1'].astype(str)),
                     name='D1_'+str(i+1)) for i,j in list(zip(range(combfactor), 
                                                     combfactor*list(range(max(df['Cnt'])+1))))]    

newdf = pd.concat(serlist, axis=1, keys=[s.name for s in serlist])
```

Output

```
print(newdf)

#        D1_1     D1_2     D1_3     D1_4     D1_5     D1_6     D1_7     D1_8  \
# 0      2827     2827     2827     2827     2827     2827     2827     2827   
# 1      2861  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"     2861  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"   
# 2   "blank"     2861     2861  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"   
# 3   "blank"  "blank"  "blank"     2861  "blank"  "blank"     2861     2861   
# 4   "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"     2861  "blank"  "blank"   
# 5      2177     2177     2177     2177     2177     2177     2177     2177   
# 6      2113     2113  "blank"  "blank"     2113     2113  "blank"  "blank"   
# 7   "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"   
# 8      2711     2711     2711     2711     2711     2711     2711     2711   
# v9      2067  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"   
# 10  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"     2067     2067  "blank"  "blank"   
# 11  "blank"     2067     2067  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"     2067  "blank"   
# 12     2957     2957     2957     2957     2957     2957     2957     2957   
# 13     2407     2407     2407     2407     2407     2407     2407     2407   
# 14     2893     2893     2893     2893     2893     2893     2893     2893   

#        D1_9    D1_10   ...       D1_15    D1_16    D1_17    D1_18    D1_19  \
# 0      2827     2827   ...        2827     2827     2827     2827     2827   
# 1   "blank"     2861   ...        2861  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"   
# 2   "blank"  "blank"   ...     "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"   
# 3      2861  "blank"   ...     "blank"     2861     2861     2861  "blank"   
# 4   "blank"  "blank"   ...     "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"     2861   
# 5      2177     2177   ...        2177     2177     2177     2177     2177   
# 6      2113     2113   ...     "blank"  "blank"     2113     2113  "blank"   
# 7   "blank"  "blank"   ...     "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"   
# 8      2711     2711   ...        2711     2711     2711     2711     2711   
# 9   "blank"     2067   ...     "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"   
# 10     2067  "blank"   ...     "blank"  "blank"     2067     2067  "blank"   
# 11  "blank"  "blank"   ...        2067  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"     2067   
# 12     2957     2957   ...        2957     2957     2957     2957     2957   
# 13     2407     2407   ...        2407     2407     2407     2407     2407   
# 14     2893     2893   ...        2893     2893     2893     2893     2893   

#      D1_20    D1_21    D1_22    D1_23    D1_24  
# 0      2827     2827     2827     2827     2827  
# 1      2861  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"     2861  
# 2   "blank"  "blank"     2861     2861  "blank"  
# 3   "blank"     2861  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  
# 4   "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  
# 5      2177     2177     2177     2177     2177  
# 6   "blank"     2113     2113  "blank"  "blank"  
# 7   "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  
# 8      2711     2711     2711     2711     2711  
# 9   "blank"  "blank"     2067     2067  "blank"  
# 10  "blank"     2067  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  
# 11  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  "blank"  
# 12     2957     2957     2957     2957     2957  
# 13     2407     2407     2407     2407     2407  
# 14     2893     2893     2893     2893     2893  

# [15 rows x 24 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, that is 1 combination of different "blanks" covering duplicates, but a next combination of blanks covering the duplicates of the same column is the second output i posted. e.g: There index 1 is now "blank" and index 2 has the number, 3 and 4 are "blank" again. Next combination should give index 1 & 2 "blank", 3 the number and 4 "blank" aigain, etc... this should give 4*2*3 = 24 combinations of blanks covering the doubles. Hope my explanation is a bit clear? :)

Comment: See update where `itertools` and `functools` had to be imported as combinations for each grouping are concatenated and joined to original dataframe than iterated for the *blanks*. Though to reach all 24 combs of the larger set *2861* yields the other lower number dups with all *blanks* for their grouping in some columns. Whew! Tell wife and kids, nothing is ever easy!

Comment: Wow nice, difficult problem! I'll tell my wife, she will be happy that I don't spent all my evenings sorting out this problem ;). Thanks again!